# Detect mouse on Windows Runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, touch, mouse

I'd like to instruct users of my app to either "click" or "tap", depending whether they have a mouse or a touch screen.

Basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
if(Controls.hasMouse())
   ShowMessage("Click here to continue");
else
   ShowMessage("Tap here to continue");
```

Any ideas how to detect if a mouse is connected to the system?

Comment: Note that Windows RT is a SKU of Windows. You probably meant Windows Runtime, usually shortened to WinRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem:

```
using namespace Windows::Devices::Input;

MouseCapabilities^ mcap = ref new MouseCapabilities();
bool has_mouse = mcap->MousePresent == 1;
```

Comment: Have you considered checking if touch capability is present too? You wouldn't want to ask the user to touch the screen if the screen does not have touch capabilities, right?

Comment: Valid point. In our case it's reasonable to expect the user to have either of the two, but in future it might be needed to tell the difference between pen (Do users 'tap' with their pen? Or is there are more appropriate term?), Kinect-like body gestures and voice commands.